# Return lengths of repeating substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring, python-itertools

For a given substring, I need to determine all the lengths, in order, of the repeating chains of that substring in a given string.

Example: for the substring `ATT` and a string `ATTATTATT GGG ATTATT GGG ATT`, I want to return `(3,2,1)`.

I think I have a solution, but it's inelegant and potentially slow (written below). I wanted to use `more_itertools.consecutive_groups()` on the start locations of the substring, but couldn't figure out how to adjust for the substring being longer than length 1.

```
spans = [i.span() for i in 
         finditer(substring,string)]
lengths = []
runninglength = 1
for i in range(len(spans)):
    if i == len(spans)-1:
        lengths.append(runninglength)
    
    elif spans[i][1] == spans[i+1][0]:
        runninglength += 1
    
    else:
        lengths.append(runninglength)
        runninglength = 1
    return tuple(lengths)
```

Is there a faster, less confusing way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is a string like `ATTGGGATTATT GGGATT` possible? If so, what would be your expected result?

Comment: @Nick, I left the spaces in the string out of habit. There would be no spaces in any string. The string you mentioned is possible and if the fixed substring was ATT, the expected result is (1,2,1). If the fixed substring was GGG, the expected result would be (1,1). Edit: That said, the spaces shouldn't affect anything, since whatever algorithm finding the substrings should skip over the spaces, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` to find all the non-overlapping matches in the string, then divide the length of the captured matches by the length of the search string to get the number of consecutive matches. For example:

```py
import re

s = 'ATTATTATT GGG ATTATT GGG ATT'
sub = 'ATT'
sl = len(sub)

regex = re.compile(f'((?:{sub})+)')

lens = [len(m) // sl for m in regex.findall(s)]
print(lens)
```

Output:

```py
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to do without relying on splitting across spaces (which may or may not be in the string -- my example might have been misleading). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the below is what you want to do:

```
sub_string = 'ATT'
string = 'ATTATTATT GGGATTATT GGGATT'

count = tuple(sub.count(sub_string) for sub in string.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tuple(each.count('ATT') for each in 'ATTATTATT GGG ATTATT GGG ATT'.split(' '))
```

Output:

```
(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: I think I would expect something different from `'ATTGGGATTATT'`

Comment: @Mark, you're right. I need spaces to be able to be ignored if desired. Something like what you said should return (1,2).